# MYSQL Error on IF NOT EXISTS/WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm using a simple IF NOT EXISTS/WHERE NOT EXISTS statement in my SQL query (I tried both) and I'm always getting a mysql error, no idea why. Tried it with different quotation marks, checked my MySQL server version, etc.

These are the statements I used

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE kurs_users.uid = 'someuser') 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO kurs_users(uid) VALUES ('someuser') 
END
```

and

```
INSERT INTO kurs_users 
VALUES ('', 'someuser') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE uid = 'someuser');
```

Error messasge:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE uid =
>   'someuser')' at line 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `values` statement does not allow a `where` clause.  Change it to `insert . . . select`.  However, in MySQL, you can't have a `where` clause without a `from`, so use a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO kurs_users 
    select col1, col2
    from (select '' as col1, 'someuser' as col2) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE uid = 'someuser');
```

I would also encourage you to list the columns explicitly in the `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO kurs_users(UnnamedColumn, UserName) 
    select col1, col2
    from (select '' as col1, 'someuser' as col2) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE uid = 'someuser');
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the 'where not exists'.
Statement: INSERT INTO kurs_users(id, uid) select '', 'someuser' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE uid = 'someuser');

Error:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM kurs_users WHERE uid = 'someuser')' at line 1