# MySQL Existance Syntax Error

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a MySQL syntax error for the following query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `guilds` WHERE `ID` = 123)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO guilds (`ID`, `Prefix`, `Join`, `Leave`) VALUES ('123', '//', '    Welcome!', 'Goodbye!');
END
```

I don't know what's causing this, could somebody help?

I've looked at other examples of this, and they seem to be identical to this one, with the exception that this one doesn't work.

Comment: You can use flow statements like `IF` only in fuctions or procedures, or triggers....

Comment: `if` like that only works in sprocs. it does not work as an independent query statement.

Comment: I see a missing semi-colon after at the end of the INSERT statement.

Comment: Why not use `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: @d3r1ck Added the missing ;.

Comment: @Arraying, does that fix the problem?

Comment: @d3r1ckNope, it doesn't, unfortunately...
If it helps, here is the error message

Comment: @d3r1ck #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM guilds WHERE `ID`=123)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO guilds (' at line 1

Comment: @Arraying you were given the answer in the 1st comment...

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696604/mysql-error-on-if-not-exists-where-not-exists, that will solve your problem.

Comment: @juergendthen then what would the query be in my situation:
//check if a row exists where the id is 123, if no, create one, with prefix, join and leave being //, Welcome!, and Goodbye!
?

Comment: @Arraying check the 4th comment from the top